# MS Visual Studio Error: Expected Constant Expression

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Take the following code.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
unsigned power(unsigned b, unsigned e){return e?b*power(b, e-1):1;}//Raises base b to a power e
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{const unsigned lev=5, len=power(2, lev)-1;
int arr[len]; //Error according to Microsoft visual studio
cout<<"The code worked."<<endl;
}
```

My Codeblock compiler is fine with the array allocation, but Microsoft visual studio says that line expects a constant expression.

I understand the difference between stack and dynamic allocation from heap. But In this instance, the parameter `len` is determined statically anyway, at the compile time. I store the value in a variable (instead of directly using 5) only because my test cases use different `len` each time I run the program.

So is there any way to make visual studio work with it? Or should I resort to dynamic allocation, even though CodeBlock accepts it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce (VS2013). Which Visual studio are you using?

Comment: [Can not replicate](http://rextester.com/GWXU44735). Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I am using VS 2010.

Comment: maybe it's having a problem with the implied data type. try specifying int.

Comment: @Della Cannot reproduce on VS2010 as well. Please make sure that the error is on the exact line, that you are showing us.

Comment: mark your function as `constexpr`

Comment: There is a difference between compile-time constants and variables which can't be modified once they have been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int arr[len];
```

`len` is not a compile time constant expression (it needs to be computed with `power` function, after all).

C (*as opposed to C++*) allows for arrays whose length is not know until runtime. Those are called "variable length arrays" (VLAs).

As such, your code is not valid C++. It works with GCC because that compiler (by default) extends C++ with some additional "features", VLAs being one of them.

---

> But In this instance, the parameter `len` is determined statically anyway, at the compile time.

No, it is initialised to the return value of the `power` function. C++ (by default) does not allow for "super compilation" (executing arbitrary amount of code which is deemed to have a constant result), thus the function can only be called at runtime.

Starting with C++11 there's the `constexpr` keyword which allows you to mark certain (restricted) functions such that they will be executed during complie time when their parameters are compile time constants.

Comment: Yes but function `power` can be made `constexpr`

Comment: @mpiatek indeed, added a short note regarding constexpr